# for Loop running for long long int but not for unsigned long long int

Tags: c++

I am running the following for loop

```
for(unsigned long long int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--){
    cin>>L[i];
}
```

when the program reaches this code segment, it stops responding.
But when i remove the `unsigned`, like this

```
for(long long int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--){
    cin>>L[i];
}
```

it works fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: can an unsigned ever get smaller than 0 ?

Comment: @Oliv Not true. `0` is not positive.

Comment: @BrennanVincent! Aichhh.... All unsigned are not negative integers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i` is unsigned, `i >= 0` is always true, and so your loop condition is always satisfied.

When `i` is 0, `i--` causes `i` to be equal to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()`, which varies by system, but a typical value would be 9223372036854775807. Your loop counter would then start counting down from there.

Comment: @Krishanu yes infinitely

Comment: @Krishanu yes, it will keep running and never stop.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 `cin >> L[i]` is i/o... (but it is UB for another reason, which is that once the loop counter wraps around you will start reading past the end of the array. But teh OP's question has nothing to do with this.)

Comment: I understand, Thanks!

Comment: @BrennanVincent ups sorry, but then actually I dont understand the reported behaviour "stops responding". deleted the comment

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 well who knows. If it's straightforwardly compiled to the obvious machine instructions on a typical x86 OS, it should segfault. But according to the standard it is UB, so who knows what is actually happening. You would have to look at the assembly output to be sure.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that may be because of the `cin>>L[i];` statement. The program must be accessing bogus index, which causes it to crash, Maybe!

Comment: yeah it is UB but for different reason I initially thought